# How to fire off multiple PHP scripts in the background?

Tags: php, cakephp, process

this side of PHP is rather new to me.

I am interested in firing off a large number (25-50) separate processes from a parent script.  I would like for the parent script to not wait for these other scripts to complete AND I would like for these other scripts to run in parallel.

Each script would run for a specified amount of time calling a webservice.

Can anyone give me some direction with this?  I'm not asking for a coded answer specifically, but I just need some guidance.

Much thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a seperate PHP process or a command line process. Either google PHP fork, or PHP exec to get started...

Comment: Hi dan360.  It would be a separate PHP script.  I'll check on those two items you noted.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to achieve. @Julien's forking method could work, but this is not preferable if your web service calls are data intensive. I am not saying that forking is bad on the contrary it works, but with the ammount of different wev services you want to call you should have a way manage things better.

Another thing that you can do is base this on cronjobs. For example if you're calling these webservices for some users in your app create a queue - a DB table that you add records that need to be processed. If you are using Cake use the [Cake Shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html). Then set up cronjobs that call a the shells that processes these records every now and then. Divide all services is separate queues - at least for those that are very different in logic. This way you will also divide your risk because if there is a failure in one of the web service calls you would not jeopardise all in some way. Have separate logging abilities for each queue which will enable you to quickly track down problems. With consuming web services very often problems are external to your application.

Comment: Borislav, thank you for a very well written approach.  I will definitely consider the strategy you proposed!